# How to stop a dictionary shuffling? (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, menu

I have designed a menu and I'm using a dictionary for the values. I would like to stay with a dictionary if at all possible. The only problem is that a dictionary automatically shuffles its contents and I need it, quite obviously, to print the menu in the order I want. My code so far looks like this:

```
menu = {}
menu['1']="Encrypt message" 
menu['2']="Decrypt message"
menu['3']="Secure Encrypt Message"
menu['4']="Exit"
while True:
    for number, name in menu.items():
      print(number+")", name)
    selection=input("Please Select:")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Python.

Comment: Use a `collections.OrderedDict` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered. You want a list or another ordered type.

```
menu = [
    "Encrypt message",
    "Decrypt message",
    "Secure Encrypt Message",
    "Exit",
    ]
for n, x in enumerate(menu, start=1):
    print("{}) {}".format(n, x))
selection = input("Please select: ")
```

Or perhaps you want to include a data item with your text labels:

```
menu = [
    # TODO: define your encrypt, decrypt and secure_encrypt functions
    ("Encrypt message", encrypt),
    ("Decrypt message", decrypt),
    ("Secure Encrypt Message", secure_encrypt),
    ("Exit", sys.exit),
    ]
for n, (label, _) in enumerate(menu, start=1):
    print("{}) {}".format(n, label))
selection = input("Please select: ")
assert 1 <= selection <= len(menu), "TODO: better error handling"
menu[selection - 1][1]()
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary keys, by definition, are not in any particular order.  You would either need some other structure to represent their order (like a list), or you could sort the keys (if there is an appropriate sort order).

You could also use an `OrderedDict`, if you want the keys in the order they were inserted.

Comment: The sort order would be the number order, any ideas on how that would be done?

Comment: `sorted(menu.keys())`